# mod_rewrite only a blank url (not one with parameters) http://www.example.com -> http://www.example.com/something

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect a blank url http://www.example.com to http://www.example.com/something with mod_rewrite only if it is the pure blank url.
As soon as there is a file- or pathname or parameters appended to it it must not be rewritten.
Tried a lot of stuff but allway run into too many redirects.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/something [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /something [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect only landing page with no query string to `/something`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it!